# Convert dictionary of lists to dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Current output is of format, dictionary of lists

```
{
    "majestic-service-1.324.02070909": [
        "/home/robotics/arm-services/FeaturesDir.yaml",
        "/home/robotics/arm-service/majestic-service.tar.gz"
    ],
}
```

and I'm looking to change that output format to something like below.(dictionary of dictionary)

```
{
    "majestic-service-1.324.02070909": {
        "yaml_file": "/home/robotics/arm-services/FeaturesDir.yaml",
        "tar_file": "/home/robotics/arm-services/majestic-service-1.324.02070909.tar.gz",
        "kind": "FeaturesDir"
    }
}
```

Corresponding code snippet that I've tried,

```
 output_dict = {}
 for file in application_files:
    match = re.match(regex_pattern, os.path.basename(file))
    if match:
         if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "FeaturesDir.yaml")):
              output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)] = {os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "FeaturesDir.yaml")}
              output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)].append(file)
              output_dict["Kind"] = "FeaturesDir"
         elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "output_path/Deviations.yaml")):
                output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)] = {os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "output_path/Deviations")}
                output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)].append(file)
                output_dict["Kind"] = "Deviations"

# where the function file_without_extension, will return - majestic-service-1.324.02070909 from majestic-service-1.324.02070909.tar.gz
```

It reports the following error

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: set's does not have an append method - Use `add` instead. Also the regexp is not included in the question, so it's hard to understand exactly what you want here. It's likely possible to simplify this a great deal. Try posting on code-review if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because in this line `output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)] = {os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "output_path/Deviations")}` you're using {} brackets which for python are intended as the data type called set. Sets don't have append attribute, they have add attribute instead but it's a completely different data type. That's why it shows you that kind of error!

Comment: I tried removing that as well, no luck though..
same error.

Comment: I've modified to `output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "FeaturesDir.yaml")`

Comment: in both lines? because two of them presented {} parenthesis

Comment: Yes , on both the lines

Comment: Have you restarted kernel? Because if the error is still 'set' object ... it means that `output_dict[file_without_extension(match.string)]` is a set and I can't understand why

Comment: Hey I figured it out, I didn't initialise the second dictionary :)